# FTP or HTTP for internal collaboration?

Tags: http, ftp, collaboration

I'm making an app with a friend. I have a server which supports PHP and MySQL which my app is based on.

So we need to collaborate when making the app.

We are using Dreamweaver and NetBeans and apps on our phones...

The question is:
Is it secure to put the app we are developing on the web while its under development, and what should we use to protect it from the outside world?
Will Password Protected FTP be a good solution? or HTTP with a password protected folder?

I have seen there is a problem in HTTP protected folders. The login accepts a some other passwords too. Like if the password is helloworld123 and you login with helloworld it would accept and login?

SO I think HTTP will not be a good solution. And if it is then how should i make it more secure?
So what should I use? FTP or HTTP? thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing an application, you should really be developing it locally.

You will *rapidly* tire of testing a change by uploading it to a remote server.

Additionally, what happens if your friend makes a change, how do you know that he has made that change? You will very quickly get collisions in code which totally ruin your collaboration.

So first of all, you should both install a LAMP/MAMP/WAMP stack locally. You should be testing everything locally, and you don't need to publish it to a server to test.

Then, you should be using some kind of version control in order to add any changes you make to a remote repository. This means that then you and your friend can work in isolation from each other, and then commit your own changes to a repository, and then you can merge the branches as you go.

When your application is then finished, you can then start to think about putting it into a production ready state by adding it to a server.

Sign up for an account at GitHub.com read as much as you can about how version control works, because if you intend to work together on *anything* you need to wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 0):

If possible I'd always reccomend using `localhost` and syncing with `Dropbox` or any similar app. Otherwise you can try `.htaccess` to prevent anyone other than you and your friend from accessing your page.

Comment: thats a good idea, and till now we are using that, 
but is there an app for Android which can setup the Apache, PHP, MySQL server...
If there is then Dropbox is a good idea... otherwise i'll have to look for something else...

Comment: I'm sure that there are syncing applications for phones, although I'm not sure about apache and sql.